# How do you order Models with M2M relationship to avoid NameSpace errors?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to order these models that have a M2M relationship.

When I try to syncdb, I can't because the Model related model is not in the namespace yet, so I get:

> NameError: name 'FavoriteQuestion' is not defined

If I switch places, I get:

> NameError: name 'UserProfile' is not defined

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    """User Profile customizations"""  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)  
    favorite_questions =  models.ManyToManyField(Question, through=FavoriteQuestion,  
                                                 related_name='favorited_by')  
    badges = models.ManyToManyField(Badge, through=Award,  
                                    related_name='awarded_to')  


class FavoriteQuestion(models.Model):  
    """A favorite Question of a User."""  
    question      = models.ForeignKey(Question)  
    user          = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='user_favorite_questions')  
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Here is the TraceBack:

> ```
> $ python manage.py syncdb   
>     Traceback (most recent call last):   
>       File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>   
>         execute_manager(settings)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 439, in execute_manager   
>         utility.execute()   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 380, in execute   
>         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv   
>         self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 221, in execute   
>         self.validate()   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate   
>         num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors   
>         for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 131, in get_app_errors   
>         self._populate()   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 58, in _populate   
>         self.load_app(app_name, True)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 74, in load_app   
>         models = import_module('.models', app_name)   
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module   
>         __import__(name)   
>       File "/Users/Bryan/work/APPNAME/forum/models.py", line 434, in <module>   
>         class FavoriteQuestion(models.Model):   
>       File "/Users/Bryan/work/APPNAME/forum/models.py", line 437, in FavoriteQuestion   
>         user          = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='user_favorite_questions')   
>     NameError: name 'UserProfile' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the favourite_question field on the UserProfile.

As long as each FavouriteQuestion has a user associated with it the model instance API will give you access to a list of favourite questions for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the the Class to the field constructor, pass in the string of the class name. Django will do the leg work of figuring out how to hook up the models without relying on the class definitions to exist at the point in the module where the other class is being defined. I would actually do this for all of your relations you define:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    """User Profile customizations"""  
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', unique=True)  
    favorite_questions =  models.ManyToManyField('Question', through='FavoriteQuestion',  
                                                 related_name='favorited_by')  
    badges = models.ManyToManyField('Badge', through='Award',  
                                    related_name='awarded_to')  


class FavoriteQuestion(models.Model):  
    """A favorite Question of a User."""  
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='user_favorite_questions')  
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```